# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Freeze

Tags: unity, 16.04, gui, freeze

currently I've installed on my Lenovo G50-30 Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
Now I got after the system is running for a short or a longer time desktop freezes. As desktop software I use Unity, also tried Xfce -> same problem.

Also the RAM was changed and no improvement was able to be seen.
Could you please give me some ideas were the root cause could be?

my system:

Linux jon-Lenovo-G50-30 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: In my case installing graphic driver fixed my system.
[Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) But if your PC has AMD's one, it looks no way so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade to kernel 3.19.0-59-generic helped in my case.
Probably another grafic driver is loaded in this older kernel.
Problem solved.

Comment: really this works? :o

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem this morning. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a DELL Latitude E5450 and could fix the problem as follows:

Get into GRUB menu while holding ESC key on startup. When GRUB menu appears, I've pressed "e" to change the boot options. I added "nosetmode" as described here: [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Afterwards I could boot and get a terminal prompt (no GUI). In the /var/log/syslog I found problems regarding to gdm3 (gnome). I removed it and erverything works fine.

Quick fix: Remove gdm3 and gnome if installed afterwards.